# Как отправить несколько GET-запросов одновременно через requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, requests

Есть `requests`, нужно отправить несколько GET-запросов не по очереди, а одновременно, без ожидания `response`.

Как это сделать просто и лаконично?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests


def get(url):
    return requests.get(url).text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i}' for i in range(10)]
    # создадим процессов по количеству ядер
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        # res - это список результатов полученных от всех функций get
        res = pool.map(get, urls)
    print(res)
```