# Как отправить 500 запросов на сайт в секунду python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, asyncio

У меня есть сайт с которого я бы хотел получить ошибку 404 если страница не существует и код ответа 200, если страница на сайте существует, я использовал асинхронный код для отправки get запросов на сайт, использовал c aiohttp ClientSession, однако заметил, что 500 запросов отправляются в течении 2х-3х секунд, есть ли возможность отправлять 500 запросов в секунду? Так чтобы к примеру в списке уже были указаны ссылки и написав какой-то код, все 500 запросов отправлялись сразу, возможно с какой-то микрозадержкой, но все 500 запросов по идее также должны выполниться одновременно.

Могли бы посоветовать что-то?
Или написать пример того, как это лучше сделать и что использовать?

Имеющийся у меня код:

```
from asyncio import gather, create_task, run, sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from time import sleep as ssleep
from datetime import datetime

global success_number
success_number = 0

headers = {}
headers["accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
headers["cookie"] = "_ga=GA1.2.911762608.1640089286; _gid=GA1.2.1225094414.1640089286; __oagr=true"
headers["sec-ch-ua"] = '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Microsoft Edge";v="96"'
headers["sec-ch-ua-mobile"] = "?0"
headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"] = "Windows"
headers["sec-fetch-dest"] = "document"
headers["sec-fetch-mode"] = "navigate"
headers["sec-fetch-site"] = "none"
headers["sec-fetch-user"] = "?1"
headers["upgrade-insecure-requests"] = "1"
headers["user-agent"] = UserAgent().random


async def get_user_info(url, unique_id):
    global success_number
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
            date_time = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y | %H:%M:%S')
            if response.status == 200:
                success_number += 1
            print(str(date_time) + ' | ' + str(response.status) + ' ID: ' +str(unique_id) + ' SUCCESS: ' +str(success_number))
    
    
async def runner():
    min_id = 0
    max_id = 10000
    tasks = []
    chunk = 500
    pended = 0
    for current_id in range(max_id):
        unique_id = min_id + current_id
        url = f'https://lardi-trans.ua/user/{unique_id}/'
        tasks.append(create_task(get_user_info(url, unique_id)))
        if len(tasks) == chunk or pended == max_id:
            await gather(*tasks)
            tasks = []

            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(runner())
```

Comment: Посоветую для начала проверить, не упираешься ли в загрузку процессора когда 500 запросов в течении 2-3 секунд отправляются.

Comment: вообще не должны, асинхронность не так работает. то о чем вы говорите - есть разбиение на потоки

Comment: @Геннадий П процессор вообще не нагружается

Comment: @finally Вообще асинхронность именно для того и нужна, что бы отправить много запросов, а потом ждать ответы. С учетом GIL и времени на переключение контекста потоков, процессора будет потрачено гораздо больше в случае использования потоков для решения данной задачи, особенно если потоков больше, чем ядер процессора. Ну это в теории, дальше надо смотреть уже конкретный код и как то и другое реализовано в питоне.

Comment: @MaximChyorny Надо посмотреть на код, может его можно как то по другому написать. И что именно происходит у вас 2-3 секунды, отправляются запросы или выполняются запросы, т.е. уже вместе с получением ответа ? Ведь сайт на который вы нацелены может просто не выдерживать такую нагрузку и тормозить с ответом. Надо собрать подробную статистику, сколько времени уходит на собственно отправку запроса и сколько на ожидание ответа. Вывести мнимум, максимум, среднее, медиану. Далее надо подобрать такое количество одновременных запросов, что бы сайт хорошо справлялся и время ответа не росло по экспоненте

Comment: @MaximChyorny Если предположить, что на сайте nginx, статика и HDD, то много параллельных запросов будут выполняться медленнее, просто потому, что диску надо больше головками двигать, переключаясь с задачи на задачу. Да и у SSD есть понятие IOPS и легко можно в него упереться. Если же там какой то другой web-сервер, то вполне возможно что вы в его потоки упираетесь и ваши соединения на его стороне ждут в очереди. Если файлы больше, чем размер блока диска и вам надо знать только существование, то стоит попробовать использовать partial (Range) запрос только первых байт

Comment: @MaximChyorny И судя по вашим комментариям у меня ощущение, что вы пытаетесь отправить 500 запросов, дождаться, пока выполняться все 500 и только после этого отправлять следующую пачку. Такая волнообразная нагрузка явно не идет на пользу не целевому сайту, не вашей программе. Лучше постоянно поддерживать определенное количество запросов в работе, забирая из очереди очередные ссылки, как только предыдущий запрос выполнен. И скорее всего таких веркеров нужно будет меньше, чем 500 параллельно. При этом общая работа будет выполнена быстрее

Comment: 500 запросов на локалхост отправляются за 3-4ms. За 500ms получаю назад все ответы. Сессия такая: `aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10))`. Для 10000 запросов 70ms отправка, 9s получение ответов.

Comment: Родительский процесс ставит метку `now + 10s`, порождает 50 детей, каждый ребёнок ждёт наступления нужного времени, посылает 10 запросов как только время пришло. Внутри питона конкуренции не будет. Все вопросы к сети.

Comment: асинхронность синхронизируется через await. покажите код- нарисуем как исправить

Comment: ребят, я обновил, посмотрите

Comment: Ну да, как я и ожидал, 500 запросов и ждем все ответы. Все таки померяйте среднее и максимальное время между отправкой конкретного запроса и получением ответа на него, меняя размер чанка. думаю там будет явно видно что скажем до 50 запросов все быстро, а после начинаются провалы отдельных запросов по времени. А вообще конечно все печально. Там сейчас id пользователя например 12761437190. Если ваш алгоритм ускорить в 3 раза то вы переберете все id за 295 дней. И это при экстремальной круглосуточной нагрузке на сайт. Вам бы понравилось, если бы вашу БД грузили год под 100% ?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy могли бы код на пастебин хотя бы загрузить, чтобы более лучше понимал, в таком виде ваш комментарий менее понятен

Answer (score 1):

самый простой пример, который должен решить проблему:

```py
import requests

from threading import Thread


def send_request(...):
    ...


thread_pool = [
    Thread(target=send_request, args=[]) for _ in range(500)
]

for thread in thread_pool:
    thread.start()
```

Comment: Код выполнился за 5 секунд, сайт отвечает примерно за секунду даже меньше, мне нужно так, чтобы все 500 запросов отправились сразу и примерно через секунды две я получил все ответы. Сайт очень быстрый и хорошая ддос атака вряд ли на его пойдет. Есть ли способы улучшить ваш код, чтобы примерно за 2 секунды он выполнился?

Comment: это не дос атака

Comment: мне просто необходимо получить код ответа от всех 500 запросов в течении минимального времени, меньше времени - быстрее я смогу отправить следующие 500 запросов, чтобы получить код ответа от сайта о наличии ошибки 404 или кода ответа 200.

Comment: то о чем вы говорите - практически невозможно в реалиях питона. попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `multiprocessinsg`

Comment: 10000 запросов выполнились за 2 минуты и 15 секунд, по моим подсчетам 10000/500 запросов за секунду и с ожиданием в 2 секунды - это одна минута ровно. 10000/500=20  после 20*3  3 - это кол-во секунд, для того, чтобы полноценно выполнились 500 запросов, а то есть в течении 3-х секунд, итого такой бы код меньше занимал времени на исполнение, а именно на минуту и 15 секунд меньше, чем ваш. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: тут посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898662/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-requests?rq=1

Comment: минуты 4-5 все выполнялось